# Can I use typeid() to know whether a type is enum?

Tags: c++, enums, typeid

Can I use the `typeid` / `type_info` somehow to detect whether some type is an `enum` (any enumerator) ?

the following works fine to detect whether a variable has type `int`

```
template<typename T>
bool is_int( T var )
{
  return strcmp( typeid(T).name(), typeid(int).name() ) == 0; 
}
```

but I can't use a similar version for enums - the string returned by name() differs between Linux and Windows

```
template<typename T>
bool is_enum( T var )
{
  // can I use typeid here?
  // eg. string_contains( typeid(var).name(), "enum" ); 
}
```

I've seen the templated version in Boost, but we can't use this library yet...

Comment: What problem are you really trying to solve?

Comment: You shouldn't use `strcmp` on the `name()`s; `std::type_info` supports [comparison operators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_info/operator_cmp). Besides, the name of *any* type might differ from one platform to the next.

Comment: @larsmans: and the names are not guaranteed to be unique.

Comment: @MarkB: I need to create an `is_enum(T)` using simple tools. No Boost, no C++11. Perhaps something of the sort `if( !is_int(T) && !is_pointer(T) && sizeof(T)==sizeof(some_dummy_enumerator) ) return true;`   - sorry about the syntax; I hope you understand what I'm trying to achieve

Comment: what prevents you from using boost libraries? In our company we also have very strict rules for using open source libraries / tools. But our "lawyers" approved it finally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two issues with your approach:

- you assume than names are unique. They are not (at least, the Standard does not guarantee that they are).
- you assume that because you can detect one type, you can detect a family with the same mechanism.

If you want to know the static type of a variable, a compile-time mechanism is probably best. There are specific C++11 traits for this: `std::is_enum<T>` has a `value` static member which will be `true` or `false` depending on whether `T` is an `enum` or not.

Answer (score 3):

In the latest C++ standard, C++11, there is already functionality for checking (at compile-time) if a type is an [`enum`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_enum) or an [`int`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_integral).

Comment: The question asks whether `typeid` can be used for that. I'm guessing not, but the answer should say so explicitly since that was the question asked.

Comment: so, guys, really, my only hope (since I have non-C++11 compilers) is the boost version of is_enum(), right ?